# needs a portable php interpreter for windows

Tags: php, portable

I have a simple question. is there a portable php interpreter avalible for free? also is there an online compiler for php which supports html tags with syntyx highlighting? and which is the best IDE for php avalible as portable?
Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with PHP itself? Put it on a thumb drive and use its built in server. Asking about an IDE is not really on topic since any answers will be opinion based.

Comment: Thanks for help, I tried what you say and it worked